# Dismiss UIAlertView in mainthread

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am calling dismissWithClickedButtonIndex in `clickedButtonAtIndex` delegate, after dismissing `alertview` i need to call an bluetooth device `[self callDevice]`.

Both are in main thread, but `[self callDevice]` is executing first, then dismissWithClickedButtonIndex is called next. So `alertview` takes sometime to resign.

Please find the code below,

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
     [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:1 animated:NO];
     [self callDevice];
}
```

How to dismiss alertview first and then to call `[self callDevice]` API?
Can anyone please suggest me the solution ?

Comment: Why are you even calling __dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:__? When any button of the alertView is clicked it dismisses eventually.

Comment: you may be aware of it, the `UIAlertView` is highly deprecated, you are supposed to use `UIAlertController` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the following `UIAlertViewDelegate` method:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

This method will be called after the dismissal animation has completed.

`UIAlertView` is deprecated. I would recommend using `UIAlertController` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use `UIAlertView` delegate method `didDismissWithButtonIndex`, which will be called after `UIAlertView` dismissed.

Use `didDismissWithButtonIndex` as follows:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

    if(buttonIndex==1){

        //UIAlertView is dismissed by clicking button at index 1, now call your method

        [self callDevice];

    }

}
```

***Note:*** `UIAlertView` is deprecated instead use `UIAlertController` for same.